# Git - Files not included in export

Tags: git, version-control, github, export, pull

So the issue is as follows:

1. I did a pull from a remote branch and got some merge conflicts
2. I used `git reset --hard <commit hash>` to revert all changes made by the earlier pull

The problem is that the files that had a conflict during the pull are now not included when I do `git export` or `archive`.

The files are there in my local repository; I can see them if I browse them on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) for example, but if I do a Git export or even if I download the repository as a ZIP file from GitHub, the files that conflicted during the pull are not included.
The only way I could get all the files was doing a Git checkout.

I tried commit, push, pull and it says `Up to Date` and the files are there and not changed, but for some reason they are not included on Git export or archive.

Again, only the files that had a conflict during the pull from a different remote repository have this problem.
How do I solve this problem, because I'm out of ideas?

Answer (score 1):

when you `git reset --hard` to get rid of the conflicts, you get rid of the whole merge including what ever you pulled down. You have 3 choices:

1. Reject what was on the server and reset your branch (this is what
   you did already)
2. Reject what you have and just update the branch to what the server
   has with `git reset --hard origin/master` (assuming you are working
   on the master branch).
3. Resolve the conflicts by editing the conflicted files. Then `git add
   -A` and `git merge --continue`.

Now master will contain what you need. To export, you can use `git archive` and pipe the output through tar. Or you can `git push master` to make the server reflect what you did. Add the `--force` option if you chose to reject what the server contained.